# How to rearrange elements in rows of a dataframe in R based on conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `D`, with about 100 rows, each set up to represent a different lottery ticket, like so:

```
     pA0   pA1   pA2 A0 A1 A2 
1  0.625 0.000 0.375  1 20 41
2  0.375 0.625 0.000  1 20 41
3  0.000 1.000 0.000  1 20 41
4  0.125 0.750 0.125  1 20 41
5  0.500 0.375 0.125  1 20 41
6  0.250 0.750 0.000  1 20 41
7  0.250 0.625 0.125  1 20 41
8  0.250 0.250 0.500  1 20 41
9  0.125 0.375 0.500  1 20 41
10 0.125 0.250 0.625  1 20 41
...
```

where the ^p variables represent the probability that the outcome with the same suffix will occur from the lottery. Thus with lottery 1, there is a 62.5% (`pA0`) chance that lottery A will result in an outcome of 1 (`A0`), a 0% (`pA1`) chance that lottery A will result in an outcome of 20 (`A1`), and a 37.5% (`pA2`) chance that lottery A will result in an outcome of 41 (`A2`). Similarly for all the other lotteries.

What I would like to do is create a new dataframe, say `E`, which takes the lotteries from `D` but makes the suffix `2` represent the highest outcome with a positive probability, `1` represent the second highest outcome with a positive probability and `0` represent the lowest outcome with a positive probability. For instance, row 1 would now be:

```
     pA0   pA1    pA2 A0 A1 A2
1  0.000 0.625  0.375 20  1 41
```

If a lottery has one outcome with a 0 probability it needs to be ranked last (`pA0`,`A0`), and if it has more than one outcome with a 0 probability, it doesn't matter if one is ranked over the other, as long as the outcome with the positive probability has a rank of `2`.

I'm pretty sure I could accomplish this with a whole lot of nested `if` or `ifelse` statements, but I would really rather have a solution that doesn't require this. Bonus points for a solution that generalizes to `n` outcomes per lottery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing @akrun's idea to use the apply function, but with the non-zero probability outcomes ranked by value, not expected value.

```
E <-  D

# The number of columns divided by 2 is the number of outcomes
n <- ncol(tmp) / 2

E[] <- t(apply(E, 1, function(x) {

            # x is the row , first n elements are probs, the second n
            # elements are the corresponding outcomes

            uo <- c()   # vector for unordered outcomes
            up <- c()   # vector for unordered probabilities
            oo <- c()   # vector for ordered outcomes
            op <- c()   # vector for ordered probabilities

            for (i in 1:n){             # Loop through probabilities
                if( x[i] != 0){         # if probability isn't 0, it needs to be ordered
                    op <- c(op, x[i])   # add the probability to the vector
                    oo <- c(oo, x[i+n]) # add the outcome to the vector
                }
                else{                   # if the probability is 0, it isn't ordered
                    up <- c(up, x[i] )  
                    uo <- c(uo, x[i+n] )
                }
            }

            r <- order(oo)  # Order the elements of the outcomes vector that need to be ordered

            p <- c(up, op[r]) # vector of probabilites with the 0's at the back
            o <- c(uo, oo[r]) # vector of outcomes with 0 probability outcomes in the back

            c(p,o)

        }))
```

The Data:

```
head(D,10)
     pA0   pA1   pA2 A0 A1 A2
1  0.625 0.000 0.375  1 20 41
2  0.375 0.625 0.000  1 20 41
3  0.000 1.000 0.000  1 20 41
4  0.125 0.750 0.125  1 20 41
5  0.500 0.375 0.125  1 20 41
6  0.250 0.750 0.000  1 20 41
7  0.250 0.625 0.125  1 20 41
8  0.250 0.250 0.500  1 20 41
9  0.125 0.375 0.500  1 20 41
10 0.125 0.250 0.625  1 20 41

head(E,10)
     pA0   pA1   pA2 A0 A1 A2
1  0.000 0.625 0.375 20  1 41
2  0.000 0.375 0.625 41  1 20
3  0.000 0.000 1.000  1 41 20
4  0.125 0.750 0.125  1 20 41
5  0.500 0.375 0.125  1 20 41
6  0.000 0.250 0.750 41  1 20
7  0.250 0.625 0.125  1 20 41
8  0.250 0.250 0.500  1 20 41
9  0.125 0.375 0.500  1 20 41
10 0.125 0.250 0.625  1 20 41
```

Answer (score 1):

We create an index of column names that start with 'p' using `grep`.  Looping by rows,  we multiply the p columns with the non-p columns, get the `order`, use that to arrange the values in each row.

```
E <- D
i1 <- grepl('^p', names(D))
E[] <- t(apply(D, 1, function(x) {i2 <- order(x[i1]*x[!i1])
                                  c(x[i1][i2], x[!i1][i2])}))
head(E,2)
#  pA0   pA1   pA2 A0 A1 A2
#1   0 0.625 0.375 20  1 41
#2   0 0.375 0.625 41  1 20
```

#### data

```
D <- structure(list(pA0 = c(0.625, 0.375, 0, 0.125, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.125, 0.125), pA1 = c(0, 0.625, 1, 0.75, 0.375, 0.75, 
0.625, 0.25, 0.375, 0.25), pA2 = c(0.375, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 
0, 0.125, 0.5, 0.5, 0.625), A0 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), A1 = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L), A2 = c(41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L
)), .Names = c("pA0", "pA1", "pA2", "A0", "A1", "A2"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Sorry, but I was a bit premature with accepting this answer. The way the `order` statement you suggest works is by ranking outcomes by their expectation, which is not what I need. This would, for instance, rank a 0 probability outcome over a negative outcome with positive probability. Worse, a very low probability, high outcome can be ranked lower than a very high probability, low outcome. I need outcomes with non-zero probabilities ranked from greatest to least, and then zero probability outcomes in any order ranked last.

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe  you just provided only the first row for expected output.  So, I was just guessing that this might be the output.

Comment: Ok, but I thought my question was pretty clear about outcomes being ranked, not expected outcomes being ranked. Could you suggest a way for me to make my question clearer?

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe  It becomes easier if you show the expected output for the input data showed.  I understand that you did gave the description, but descriptions can get confusing sometimes.

Comment: @BrianAlbertMonroe Perhaps `t(apply(D, 1, function(x) {i2 <- order(abs(x[i1]*x[!i1])); c(x[i1][i2], x[!i1][i2])}))` but as I mentioned earlier, it is better to show all the cases in the example and an expected output is always good.